# branch locus of the discriminant map $\overline{\mathcal{H}}_{g',r} \to \overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, algebraic-curves, branched-covers, etale-covers

Let $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$ be the moduli space of pointed, stable, genus $g$ curves. Let $\overline{\mathcal{H}}_{g',r}$ be the hurwitz space of cyclic covers of degree $r$ of genus $g$ curves ramified along $n$ points. Under some easy assumptions on $g,g',n$ and $r$. There exist a natural "discriminant" (this is how I have seen people calling it in the literature) morphism  $\delta:\overline{\mathcal{H}}_{g',r} \to \overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$, that basically forgets the "above" curve in the cover and keeps the base. This is a ramified cover of $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$, what is the branch locus of $\delta$? Also a first answer for the space of $r$-Prym curves (i.e. étale degree $r$ covers) and $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$ would be a nice starting point. A wild guess is that the components of the boundary s.t. the generic member is a nodal curve that decomposes in a genus one curve plus a genus $g-1$ should be contained in the branch locus.

Comment: For $n=0$ the branch locus is $\delta_{irr}$. This is described in many places, for instance here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0201

Comment: There seems to be a difference whether you consider the stack or the coarse moduli space. For instance, in the "twin" paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0661.pdf (page 13) the authors claim that for the coarse moduli space the discriminant morphism is ramified along some of the divisors I mentioned. Can you explain this?

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of the stack. On the level of course spaces you have to think also about automorphisms. On most divisors the generic curve has no automorphism, so this won't give you any extra ramification, but on $\delta_1$ the generic curve has $2$ automorphisms. If this generically defined automorphism does not lift to the level curve then you get ramification on the level of coarse spaces.

Comment: You can see this (informally) by computing degrees: on the level of stacks the map is étale, but then the map to the course space has "degree 1/2" downstairs (that is, on the divisor $\delta_1$) and is generically an isomorphism upstairs so has "degree 1".

Comment: Ok I see. So it should be the same also in the case of elliptic curves, right? $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{1,1}^r \to \overline{\mathcal{M}}_{1,1}$ is ramified only over $\delta_{irr}$? and with what multiplicity?

Comment: Oh no, genus one is special. As coarse spaces you have $\overline M_{1,1} \cong \mathbb P^1$ so there's no way you can have only one branch point of a ramified cover!! You can see this by thinking about automorphisms too. Branching always happens in codimension one, but in higher genus the loci of smooth curves with automorphisms have bigger codimension. This is why the only branching comes from the divisor $\delta_1$. For the projection from a modular curve you should expect branching over $\infty$ and over the points with $j$-invariants $0$ and $1728$.

Comment: A-ha, I see. In fact those are the points that have $Aut= \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6$. Ok, and how does one compute the multiplicity at each point? SHould I expect the mult at 0 to be higher than that at 1728 since there are more automorphisms that do not lift? and (I abuse of your kindness) how does the situation change on the stack?

Comment: By the way I just remarked that for $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{1,1}$ if you give no weight to the marked point, prym and spin curve are the same, cause $K=\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: You should read a textbook on modular forms! I think there's a nice treatment of all these things about modular curves in the book of Diamond-Shurman. I think I remarked on your other question that Prym=spin in genus one.